# 'FormHelper' object has no attribute 'append' while using crispy_forms in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I'm new to Django, and I am trying to style forms with crispy forms. I have a form in my app which happens to be a modelform, and I've followed what has been said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201588/1076075 to make ModelForm work with crispy_forms, but getting this error:

`'FormHelper' object has no attribute 'append'`

This is how my code looks in `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from models import Ticket, Ticketuser
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout, Fieldset, ButtonHolder
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import FormActions

class AddTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AddTicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.append(Submit('save', 'save'))

  class Meta:
    model = Ticket
    fields = ('id', 'comment')

  def process(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    data = data['comment']
    return data
```

How to get over this and style the form like how I want?

Comment: +1 for **self.helper = FormHelper(self)**. I usually use self.helper = FormHelper() which creates a lots of problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the form helper api has changed, you need to use `add_input` instead of `append` now:

Here's the example straight from [the docs](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tags.html#fundamentals):

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = 'submit_survey'

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

Comment: Pleasantly, that created a new button without any errors! Thanks for the fast reply!

I am using this for the first time, do you know how can I modify the buttons created already by modelforms?

Comment: As the other answer suggests, there was never an append in the API from the beginning. It was a typo... ;)

Answer (score 2):

`FormHelper` never had an append method AFAIK. What has indeed an `append` button is the layout:

```
self.helper.layout.append(HTML('<p>whatever<p>'))
```

http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#manipulating-a-layout

For this to work you need to have a layout set:

```
self.helper = FormHelper()
self.helper.layout = Layout('field_1', 'field_2')
```

Or have a default layout set for you http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#formhelper-with-a-form-attached

http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#manipulating-a-layout

I had a typo in my other StackOverflow example, that misled you, sorry.

Comment: No problem, have fun with crispy-forms!

Comment: when i use this I got error

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: i had some typo error. ie **self.helper = FormHelper()**, which is mentioned in the **answer above** and in the **tutorial** [http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html Layout section]. when i used **self.helper = FormHelper(self)** **which was in question** it works fine. Thanks for the comment. +1 for the answer which is very helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer, so that it's clearer, it explains why it wasn't working for you.