# Make model form crispy

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to display all my model items but add some crispy elements. However it shows my html and buttons above the model form fields instead of being under the html and above the buttons.

**Form**

```
class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_action = 'update'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            HTML("<p class='alert-info alert'>Please confirm your business contact information is updated and correct.</p>"),
            Div(
                FormActions(
                    Submit('save_changes', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"),
                ),
                css_class='row-fluid'
            )
        )

        # self.helper.add_input(Submit('save_changes', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"))

    class Meta:
        model = Business
            exclude = ('inactive',)
```

**View**

```
def index(request, token):
    try:
        business = Business.objects.get(token__token=token)
    except Token.DoesNotExist:
        business = None
    except Business.DoesNotExist:
        business = None

    return render(request, 'business/index.html', {'form': BusinessForm(instance=business)})
```

I saw [use Crispy form with ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098954/use-crispy-form-with-modelform) however it displays my model fields below the formactions and I even tried an `add_input` which did the same thing. How would I get my model form fields to be displayed between the `alert-info` and above the submit button?