# How to auto-fill fields while updating django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am creating a to-do app in django and while updating a task, i want to auto-fill the fields with previous data. Where am i messing up?

This is my views.py for the same:-

```
    task = get_object_or_404(ToDoList, id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateTaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            task.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            task.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('list'))

    else:
        form = UpdateTaskForm(instance=task)

    context = {
        'form':form,
        'task':task,
    }

    return render(request, 'TaskList/update.html', context)
```

and this is my forms.py:-

```
    class Meta:
        model  = ToDoList
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'due_date', 'completed']
```

here is my template file:-

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} Updating task {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"> Save </button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

and here is my models.py:-

```
from django.utils import timezone


# Create your models here.
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    title        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description  = models.TextField(help_text='Explain your task!', blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    due_date     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    completed    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #Author foreign key

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: try to print **task** weather it has object in it or not

Comment: object is getting printed after i have updated the task

Comment: It'll be helpful to see the full View (class or method), the entire Form class, and your template... it's possible the context variable is set and your template is just not rendering properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an instance you must also pass the same instance in the POST method also, so after

`if request.method == "POST":` add  `form = UpdateTaskForm(request.POST,instance=task)`

I guess you are using crispy forms, so according to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098954/use-crispy-form-with-modelform) They are rendering the forms using `{% crispy form %}` instead of the way you have done as `{{ form|crispy }}` maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @AartiJoshi does the `task` print the correct instance in views?

Comment: @AartiJoshi I have updated my answer, maybe it is because of crispy forms?

Comment: i removed the crispy forms. still the same !