# Django Crispy Forms; Does not load button

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I'm just have an issue with Crispy Forms; I cannot get a button to load. I've checked a ton of other StackOverflow forms, but all the examples I've followed, nothing seems to work.

example `forms.py`

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

from django import forms

from .models import ExampleModel

class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ['content', 'title']
```

example `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import ExampleModelForm

def get_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

    else:
        form = ExampleModelForm()

    return render(request, 'example_form.html', {'form': form})
```

example `example_form.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

My form loads beautifully, but I just cannot get the button to show. I've looked at the [docs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-crispy-forms/downloads/pdf/latest/) and I don't see what I am doing differently. Maybe it just doesn't play well with ModelForms? I don't know.

I've tried changing the location of `def__init__...` to be below the `Meta` class. I defined `super()` to be `super(ExampleModelForm, self)` and `self.helper = FormHelper(self)`.

I even tried to change `{% crispy form %}` to `{% crispy form form.helper %}` in the html file. It just breaks.

I tried following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098954/use-crispy-form-with-modelform) too. Just nothing is working for me.

Settings:

Django: 3.2.5

Crispy-Forms: 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out, but I don't know why it behaves like this.

```
class ExampleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ['content', 'title']
```

Basically you don't need the `def__init__(...` Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: this shouldn't work... i have the same problem but the difference is i have some forms when i override the __init__() it works but others it doesn't and i instantiate the formhelper class in the __init__()